# guessing words(like $|eeP!ng,@s,d0G) using node.js I tried to use object with aliases:{keys} saved in txt file but

Tags: javascript, string

1. My code will only guess fixed words ( less < 1000 )
2. I want to store all words/array/list/object - content in separate file (any better option except .txt)
3. I actually making a bot which reacts to fixed words only

I tried...

```js
var word = '';

function guess(obj, arry) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    var inKey = key.split(/,\s?/);
    inKey.forEach((l) => {
      l == arry[0] && (word += inKey[0]) && guess(obj[key], arry.slice(1));
    });
  });
}


var guessLetters = {
  "s, $, &, ʂ, ₰, ₷": {
    "l, |, ł, ʟ": {
      "e, ∃, ∊, £, €, ė, ɛ, ɘ , ə": {
        "e, ∃, ∊, £, €, ė, ɛ, ɘ , ə": {
          "p, ℗, ‽, ⁋, ₽, ₱, Þ, þ, ₽": "p"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "a, @": {
    "s, $, &, ʂ, ₰, ₷": "s"
  }
};
var guessThis = "₰ʟ£ɛ‽";

guess(guessLetters, guessThis.split(''));
console.log(word);
```

This solution I got after checking google and some related questions

problems...

1. repetition of same type of key like 's' for 'sleep' and 's' for 'as'
2. can't guess if 1 letter is missing in word

there is one more way I thought...

```
var translate = {
    "@, ª, ₳":"a",
    "₿, ฿":"b",
    "₵, ₡, ¢":"c",
    "£,  €, ɛ":"e",
    "₣":"f",
    respetive to all 27 letters
};
```

but...

1. bot have to check the translated word in collection every time before reacting

ex. if I have CAT in my collection and user enter CAR then...

1st method will stop at R != T and ignore user

2nd method will translate whole CAR and also check (CAR in Collection) then ignore user

Comment: I don't see the connection between this question and the discord.js library

Comment: I plan to use "Trie" but someone told me Discord has its own collection of swear words IDK that I can use them or not 